# Catch value from listitembutton to textinput kivy/python

Tags: python, list, kivy

I created a mobile app. Once a user clicks on 1 element on the list I need the text to go into another text-input

My kv file

```
#:import main main
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
<LocationButton>:
    deselected_color:0.4, 1, 1,1
    selected_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    size: (100, '48dp')
    on_press:root.test()
<ecran1>:
    nom_du_produit:le_produit
    FloatLayout:
        ListView:
            id:liste_des_produits
            size_hint:.5,.8
            pos_hint:{'x':.25,'y':.0}
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=root.L,cls=main.LocationButton) 
        TextInput:
            id:le_produit
            text:''
            font_size:20
            size_hint:.2,.1
            pos_hint:{'x':.78,'y':.75}
            background_color:1,1,1,1
            multiline:False
```

My python code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  Screen,ScreenManager,WipeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty,ListProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

class ecran1(Screen):
    L=ListProperty(['tomate','abricot'])
    nom_du_produit = ObjectProperty()

class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    L = ListProperty(['tomate', 'abricot'])
    nom_du_produit = ObjectProperty()
    def test(self):
        selection_1 = self.liste.adapter.selection[0].text
        self.nom_du_produit.text = selection_1
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ecran1()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

I tried few options but always the answer is Attribute error

Picture to better understand:[This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz23E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two different ways to accomplish what you want. Here is a modification of your `test` method that shows both:

```
def test(self):
    #App.get_running_app().root.nom_du_produit.text = self.text   # uses the ObjectProperty in the ecran1 class
    App.get_running_app().root.ids.le_produit.text = self.text    # uses the le_produit id in the TextInput class
```

Comment: The command work on this programme but on my other big program i have an error "AttributeError: 'ScreenManager' object has no attribute 'nom_du_produit'" although nom_du_produit is declared

Comment: I had a suspicion that might happen. Try this: `App.get_running_app().root.current_screen.nom_du_produit.text = self.text`

Comment: Thank to take your time when i try this command nothings happend and i don't know why?

Comment: You did put that line in the `test()` method in place of the other lines there?